# Good application downloader / installer

Tags: installation, launcher

I am in need of a software that will let me customize my own file installer/downloader.

Something like http://www.getrighttogo.com (having the files in a server is a must). The only reason I don't like http://www.getrighttogo.com is because it doesn't let me notify the users that there is an update of the files or schedule an automatic update.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out "InstallShield" or "Advanced Installer" tools. Both of them have functionality to handle and deploy application updates.

Comment: Do they let you download through web though?

Comment: Yes, they can install updates hosted on a web server, by downloading and launching them.